# Invoking Groovy script through CURL in Powershell script

Tags: curl, groovy, powershell-3.0

I need to invoke Groovy script using below CURL command:

```
curl -u username:password  -H 'Expect:' -d "script=$(<./rolepermissions.groovy); createRolePermission('Developer','Demo','userid')" JenkinsScriptConsoleURL;
```

from Powershell script. Please help me with this!

Comment: what have you tried?  what relevance has groovy here? are you actually looking for a way to replace you curl call with whatever powershell offers?

Comment: I am trying to invoke the groovy script which is in the same directory as that of my Powershell script. Using this CURL I intend to execute my function on the Jenkins located @ JenkinsScriptConsoleURL. Issue is that while I am executing this CURL in shell script and run from the Powershell console it's working absolutely fine, but I need to invoke this shell script from a Powershell script to run this.

Flow: ps1->sh->groovy->jenkins

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell expands the `$(...)` in the data string as a subexpression, thus modifying what is passed to the server. Escape the `$` to prevent that:

```
"script=`$(<./rolepermissions.groovy); createRolePermission('Developer','Demo','userid')"
#       ^
```

Comment: Thank you @Ansgar Wiechers! I have tried using the `$ in the data part but its failing to recognise "<" next to the `$(, I tried using \ and ` to overcome this, though nothing proved to be useful. Can you suggest me a way to get past this?